# python fptlib mlsd generator iteration error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib, vsftpd

I am looking for index.html file in ftp directory.  according to [docs](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/acm-docs/python/python-3.5.2-docs-html/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd) they recommend mlsd. I am trying to print results and looking for files but its not working. I have tried via terminal and its working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("192.168.10.6")
ftp.login("username", 'password')
resp = ftp.mlsd()
print(resp)



for name, facts in resp:
    print(name)
#also tried for item in resp:
```

Errors

```
<generator object FTP.mlsd at 0x7fee1870cd00>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    for name, facts in resp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 596, in mlsd
    self.retrlines(cmd, lines.append)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 468, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 399, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 361, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)`
 and enable verbose logging in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` by adding `log_ftp_protocol=YES`. I have notice the client is not sending any command after `pasv` command. by looking into ftp protocol I noticed that after login ftp decides some random port on which they will communicate. From that I thought there might be firewall problem. despite I have already allowed 20,21,22 and 960. so I tried by disabling firewall completely by `sudo ufw disable`. and ran script and it worked flawlessly. The thing that confused me alot is sometimes script worked and mostly it just timedout. 
From the current scenario I'm assuming whenever there is timeout issue it mostly have to do with firewall or security settings as when we connect to ec2 servers etc.

Also enabling debuglevel and verbose level helped me alot other I was working in dark.

Here is the log after which communication got stuck or not working.

```
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,6,200,66).\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,6,200,66).'
```

Comment: You need to open the ports from FTP passive mode port range on your firewall. Possibly you have open a part of the range only - that's why it can work sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: I'm not sure how to open passive port range in iptables or ufw. but it seems to be good idea as disabling firewall is not feasible at all.

Comment: If you need a help with that, ask at [su]. It's not a programming question.